Is there a reason why my loop, autoplay (no controls/ buttons) audio not work? HTML5
What I've seen for what I want, loop autoplay with no buttons, should be:
However, this does not work. Currently, I'm taking a "programing" class and what the games I have modded so far does:
<audio src="assets/audio/lobbyMusic.mp3" loop autoplay>This browser doesn't support audio.</audio>
And I have tried this on my HTML but it also does not work. I only think that one problem may be the CSS animations but I don't think that is likely.
Like said, I did tried thoese two methods above. The werid thing is, in another HTML the second method:
<audio src="assets/audio/lobbyMusic.mp3" loop autoplay>This browser doesn't support audio.</audio>
does work. I also tried the for paths, but it doesn't work either. And again, I don't want controls/ buttons.
Here's the code for the HTML I'm trying to add audio to:
    <head>
        <title>The Ends</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="theEndBG.css">
        <script>
        
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="context">
            <h1>The End</h1>
         </div>
        <div class="area" >
                <ul class="circles">
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                </ul>
        </div >
        
        <audio loop autoplay>
            <source src="fallingInLove.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
        </audio>
    
</body>
</html>

(And here's the CSS, also don't mind the ```` before or after code, I don't understand why this is required to post)

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,700');

*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
}


.context {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:50vh;
    
}

.context h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
}


.area{
    background: black;  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #8f94fb, #4e54c8);  
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
    
   
}

.circles{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circles li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;
    
}

.circles li:nth-child(1){
    left: 25%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}


.circles li:nth-child(2){
    left: 10%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(3){
    left: 70%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(4){
    left: 40%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 18s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(5){
    left: 65%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(6){
    left: 75%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(7){
    left: 35%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 7s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(8){
    left: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    animation-delay: 15s;
    animation-duration: 45s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(9){
    left: 20%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 35s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(10){
    left: 85%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 11s;
}



@keyframes animate {

    0%{
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    100%{
        transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
        opacity: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

}```


Local audio cannot be played by audio tag. Instead you may want to use JS to do the job. here is a sample code:
<audio id="file" src="fallingInLove.mp3" loop autoplay>
    Your browser doesn't support audio.
</audio>

and the JS:
<script>
const audio = document.getElementById('file');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  audio.play().then(() => {
    // after it finished, play again
    audio.play();
  });
});
</script>

with all these solutions, you may not be able to auto play the audio because of browser's auto play blocking policy. for further reading check MDN web guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide
